Why does my named xpath in a repository not recgnised in another class when I try to findelement?
I'm using specflow and want a Repo to store all my xpaths to make it cleaner and easier to undertsand.  So the Repo I have is
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SpecFlowProject1.Repository
{
    public class Repository
    {

        public static  By AcceptCookies = By.XPath(".//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']");
    }
}

And within the step definition file I have tried to click the element with the following commands
 [Given(@"Navigate to morrisons")]
        public void GivenNavigateToMorrisons()
        {
            driver.Url = ("https://morrisons.com");
            //Accept cookies
            driver.FindElement(AcceptCookies).Click(); 
        }

The error it gives is the name AccceptCookies does not exist in this current context
I've tried importing the Repository class but that doesn't work.  What am I missing here?
Thanks

This is a basic C# language problem.
You need to specify the class name before the property name:
driver.FindElement(Repository.AcceptCookies).Click();

If you still get a compiler error, add this to the top of your C# file:
using SpecFlowProject1.Repository;

More information:

Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)
using directive.


That being said, might I propose an alternate design that removes the need for constants used across lord knows how many files?
The Page Object Model design pattern allows you to encapsulate this information in a class specializing in a particular page. Then you can expose methods to your step bindings to provide a proper abstraction, which insulates your step definitions from UI changes that cascade to changes in your automation code.
First, I've found a "world" class that presents the application to my test framework to be a very useful concept:
public class MorrisonsWorld
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    public MorrisonsWorld(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public CookiesPopup GoToHomePage()
    {
        driver.Url = "https://morrisons.com";

        return new CookiesPopup(driver);
    }
}

Next, a little glue to make this object available to the automation framework:
[Binding]
public class Hooks
{
    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = // create web driver here

        container.RegisterInstanceAs(new MorrisonsWorld(driver));
    }
}

And the page model classes themselves:
public class CookiesPopup
{
    private static readonly By AcceptCookies = By.XPath(".//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']");

    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    public CookiesPopup(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public HomePage AcceptCookies()
    {
        driver.FindElement(AcceptCookies).Click();

        return new HomePage(driver);
    }
}

public class HomePage
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}

And finally, use them in your step bindings:
[Binding]
public class YourSteps
{
    private HomePage homepage;

    public YourSteps(MorrisonsWorld world)
    {
        World = world;
    }

    [Given(@"Navigate to morrisons")]
    public void GivenNavigateToMorrisons()
    {
        homepage = World.GoToHomePage()
                        .AcceptCookies();
    }
}

This can make for some darn clean step definitions, and those pesky locators become implementation details for your page models. No need to "share" them, because it is the page models you reuse. Since one page model returns another page model, you can navigate your entire web site in a chain of method calls, which allows Intellisense in Visual Studio to guide you better when writing automation code.
